# Add link in user drop down menu using Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

When a user is logged in they see the standard drop down menu in the top right (which is created by Laravel). I'd like to create a "Settings" page where logged in users can go to edit their personal info, upload profile photos etc.

I can't figure out how to add a link to the users drop down menu in the top right?

I've tried adding a link in web.php

Route::get('/settings', 'HomeController@settings')->name('settings');

I'm new to Laravel so am probably missing something obvious!

Comment: After adding the route, have you added the actual link to the page/header?

Answer (score 0):

The default Laravel authentication uses the layout at `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php` which you can see in the first line of the auth views (e.g. `resources/views/auth/login.blade.php`):

```
@extends('layouts.app')
```

Note that the dropdown entries are different for guests and logged-in users using `@guest`, `@else` and `@endguest`.

For the styling you can refer to the [Bootstrap Navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/).